# Is it possible to customize react build (web-pack build)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am trying to add configuration setting in react build using webpack ? Is it possible ? if so how can i do that .

[build with files-source code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gGD.png)

currently i have these files when in my build , now what i want to use this same build for different environments and use some **config.js or config.json** file to use different settings for different environments with same build.

Comment: what type of configuration ? It is possible...

Comment: what are you trying to customize?

Comment: i am trying to store some config values like base URL, some authentication keys , API end points in some config file . and these value will be different for different environments like Development , QA and Production

Comment: Hi Shafiq, you should provide as many information as you can. Could you please improve your question with more details?

Comment: @DevidFarinelli Sure , i will post some more information to clear what i want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tools like [rc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc) for load custom configurations... But if you need change the configuration after build (which is unusual) you need use some webpack plugins for inject the config file to de .html

In case that you need change after build, this could be a solution:

```js
//In the webpack.config.js file
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({ assets: "env-vars.js", append: false }),
    // This is the script that generate my env-var.js file
    new WebpackShellPlugin({ onBuildStart: ["npm run generate-env-var-file"] }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./env-vars.js",
        to: "./",
      },
    ]),
  ]
```

Comment: Yes i want configuration after build.

Comment: do you know about any plugin for that or any example link ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`EnvironmentPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) that allow you to set some environment variables in your Webpack configuration file.